# Converting a datetime into UTC with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, titanium, utc, dst

Ok, so I'm writing a Titanium app that digests a JSON feed and adds events to the users calendar. The problem I'm facing is that the JSON feed will have the datatime in local time (including daylight savings where appropriate), and the calendar needs UTC.

One simplification is the event is always in the same location (London), so the only real issue is allowing for DST (BST). So if I'm getting a date string like 2014-04-27 19:00:00 from the feed, what's the best way to get that into a javascript date object in UTC (which I think, in this case, would look like 2014-04-27T18:00:00Z, but it all depends on the time of year).

Comment: Does the feed give you *any* offset information?  If not, you won't be able to distinguish between BST and GMT [during the fall-back transition](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2014).  `2014-10-26 01:00:00` exists *twice*.  See also [the dst tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with bringing in a library, [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) with the [Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin are able to do this...

```
var input = '2014-04-27 19:00:00';
var eventDateInUtc = moment.tz(input, 'Europe/London').utc();
var output = eventDateInUtc.toDate().toISOString(); // '2014-04-27T18:00:00.000Z'
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VUjNs/)

Comment: Bit of an overhead given the target is a Titanium mobile app. Is there a way to do this without a library?

Comment: moment.js is part of Titanium already, as long as you are using alloy. Require it with `var moment = require('alloy/moment');` I would recommend using it, a well crafted library like moment.js is always first choice when it comes to date/time. Don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: Good solution, but is moment-timezone also in Titanium?  And of course, there's no avoiding the ambiguity of the fall-back transition, as I commented above.

Comment: No `moment-timezone` is not part of titanium, hence this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will help you

```
var newDate = new Date(); 
var newDateUTC = new Date(newDate.getUTCFullYear(), newDate.getUTCMonth(), newDate.getUTCDate(),  newDate.getUTCHours(), newDate.getUTCMinutes(), newDate.getUTCSeconds());
```